# Meteor execute functions synchronously

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have code where I crop an image before save it to collection, but code executes asynchronously. Insert to collection executes before image will be cropped.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'createWorkout': function(workoutFormContent, fileObj) {
        // crop image to width:height = 3:2 aspect ratio
        var workoutImage = gm(fileObj.path);
        workoutImage.size(function(error, size) {
            if (error) console.log(error);
            height = size.height;
            width = size.height * 1.5;
            workoutImage
                .gravity("Center")
                .crop(width, height)
                .write(fileObj.path, function(error) {
                    if (error) console.log(error)
                });
        });

        // add image to form content and insert to collection      
        workoutFormContent.workoutImage = fileObj;
        Workouts.insert(workoutFormContent, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    },
});
```

How I can run this code synchronously to be able insert already cropped image?

Comment: You need to run that in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write to collection only after image is cropped:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import gm from 'gm';
const bound = Meteor.bindEnvironment((callback) => {callback();});
Meteor.methods({
  createWorkout(workoutFormContent, fileObj) {
    // crop image to width:height = 3:2 aspect ratio
    const workoutImage = gm(fileObj.path);
    workoutImage.size((error, size) => {
      bound(() => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }

        const height = size.height;
        const width = size.height * 1.5;
        workoutImage.gravity('Center').crop(width, height).write(fileObj.path, (writeError) => {
          bound(() => {
            if (writeError) {
              console.log(writeError);
              return;
            }
            // add image to form content and insert to collection
            workoutFormContent.workoutImage = fileObj;
            Workouts.insert(workoutFormContent, (insertError) => {
              if (insertError) {
                console.log(insertError);
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Or use `Fibers/Future` lib, which can be used to block event loop.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it is not working. Meteor complains that function should be run in fiber.

Comment: this variant is working but time-to-time. For small images it works, but for big - not. I have tested 2 images. First image 510Kb cropped, but second 2.5Mb - not. I don't know whats the problem, I haven't seen any error messages. I just take an images and compare.

Comment: looks like it is not problem of solution you provided, but something with cropping. I'v tried to just crop image and big one are not cropped. I check your suggestion as solution.

Comment: @andrey here is our [official image processing tutorial](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Image-Processing) and [image processing in demo app](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files-Demos/blob/master/demo/server/image-processing.js#L169) take a look, should help you to solve this

Comment: here what I'm looking for! But I don't just make a thumbnail, but I want to crop image to 3:2 aspect ratio. Error I mentioned above was because I use wrong logic and tried to crop image that already shorter when new expected dimention. For example if image w:1999 h:1444 I take a <h> as shortest side and try to make width to conform 3:2 aspect ratio w=1444x1.5=2166  which bigger then 1999, so it is impossible. I have to deal with several variants to achive my goal.

Comment: Sounds like Math + Geometry task, which is beyond this topic. Assume it as solved. You can open one more question here at SO regarding image cropping.

Comment: @dr.dimirtu Yes, this question solved. Here calculation logic, if you are interested https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EKlIkG-vOQH-ngZ4s0PL3u3PNJTwx9nwoTjdkiiQF9Y/edit?usp=sharing Here 3 cases.

Comment: Here is javascript function to calc dimensions to 3:2 aspect ratio https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzxJMW